# I just failed a triage audit, but I am not sure why

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have failed [this triage audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/31524698) and would like to understand how to improve my review process.

I marked that answer as unclear (require OP edit) since there were comments not addressed by any edits (in fact it has none), and the answer displayed in the review panel was not fully addressing the OP question (in my opinion).

My decision was driven by this question "is the question detailed enough to be useful to others in the site?" since others have expressed concerns in the comments (I had the same concerns too), I decided that - for me - it was not good enough.

I would like some guidance on how to handle these kind of patterns , since I see them quite often.

Comment: You are supposed to review the post content. Not whether the author has low reputation, is inactive, or has abandoned the question. Also, comments are a red herring and can be completely ignored.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try to improve my review :)

Comment: I think you are supposed to have seen that as a good question. The author very clearly states what they are doing, what they've tried, and what they would like to accomplish, within a very clear and finite scope.

Comment: If you click on the link to the question, you'll see the answers too. Only seeing the comments on the question is not enough, especially if the question has several answers and one of them is accepted, which strongly indicates that enough detail was given in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The question is clear enough to answer.  The answers to both comments are in the question:

- *"How do you know that the current implementation is inefficient? What are your metrics?"*

  The question states that they're trying to avoid the double traversal:

  > This is traversing the list of list 2 times to get `init` and `last`, which I think can be avoided using a custom function that can do `initAndLast` in one traversal.
- *"What is the expected result if the sublists aren't all the same length?"*

  Surely it should do whatever the example code "that gives the desired output" does. I can't read Haskell especially well, but if someone states that something does the right thing, we should believe them, absent evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Agreed - a comment saying "I've tested this and I'm not sure it does what you think it does" might raise an eyebrow, but even then it shouldn't be taken as gospel. That said, I do think this particular question (while OK for StackOverflow) might've been more fitting on the Code Review stack - with it being more about improving valid code, as opposed to fixing that which is broken?

Comment: If it's OK for Stack Overflow, that's the end of the discussion, @Andrew. We do not even *consider* migrating questions unless they are off-topic on the site where they are asked. The vast, overwhelming majority of the time, whenever Stack Overflow users think a question should be migrated to Code Review, they are wrong because, first, the question is not even unsuitable for Stack Overflow, so it shouldn't be migrated anywhere, and, second, the question, as posed, is not suitable for Code Review. This case is no exception on either front.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting a migration, merely that the questioner might have had better answers if they'd chosen to post it in the format of a code review question for that particular stack (perhaps even both, to capitalise on the cross-compatibility of the topic).

Answer (score 1):

The mere fact that there are unaddressed comments doesn't automatically mean that it should be closed. Ultimately, comments just reflect the opinion of whoever left the comment, not the consensus of the community as a whole. In this case, the community consensus is that it's a good question.

Also, the question has 100% upvotes on it, so apparently the commenters didn't feel strongly enough about their opinion to downvote over it. (In fact, I think that a downvote would actually remove it from the audit pool).